# latexmk: how to continuously update the output pdf but not invoking the pdf viewer?

Tags: latexmk

`latexmk -pvc` can compile tex files continuously and update the pdf  viewer, but how can I stop it from invoking the pdf viewer automatically?

Comment: Have you tried just switching the viewer off after passing `-pvc` to countermand just the viewer? No idea if that would work, mind, but you don't say you've tried anything and that seems an obvious experiment.

Comment: @cfr It's just annoying to always need to turn it off...

Comment: Make an alias, then, and you won't have to pass `-pvc` either.

Comment: @cfr I don't see why I don't need to pass `-pvc`...

Comment: If you make an alias, you wouldn't need to. Obviously, if you don't make an alias, you would. It was just a suggestion because you indicated that typing an additional 10 characters was too much trouble. In which case, you might as well reduce it to typing just four or five `xuhmk` or whatever.

Comment: @cfr No, I meant it is annoying to close the pdf viewer every time... never mind, thank any way.

Comment: What I meant was that you could make an alias for `latexmk -pvc -view=none`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use `latexmk -pvc -view=none`.

Comment: When calling latexmk from arara, how can I stop the continuous preview in the background on my Windows PC?

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to Johns answer, here is some of the stuf I have in my `latexmk` default configuration file:

```
$latex = "latex -synctex=1  -halt-on-error %O %S";
$pdflatex = "pdflatex -synctex=1  -halt-on-error %O %S";
$sleep_time = 1;
$view = 'none';
$pdf_mode = 1;
```

The `-halt-on-error` is very handy in pvc mode, it makes latex stop at the first error and them `latexmk` is able to go back and wait for the next change to be saved

---

Addition: might be better to add options to `@extra_pdflatex_options` eventhough it is not documented.