# making latexmk use -synctex=1 by default with lualatex

Tags: luatex, latexmk, forward-inverse-search

My `.latexmkrc` is set up for passing `-synctex=1` to `pdflatex` in order to be able to jump back from my pdf viewer to the sources:

```
$pdflatex='pdflatex -synctex=1 %O %B';
$pdf_mode=1;
$pdf_previewer="start okular %O %S";
```

This works well. However, I need to use `lualatex` to compile some document, as one of the packages it uses is not supported by `pdflatex`. I can use `latexmk -lualatex -synctex=1 document.tex` to have `synctex` enabled in that case, but I'd like to tweak my `.latexmkrc` in order to be able to only have to type `latexmk -lualatex document.tex` while still getting `synctex` information (and keeping `pdflatex` as the default if `-lualatex` is not specified on the command line). I haven't succeeded so far. In particular, adding the line

```
$lualatex='lualatex -synctex=1 %O %B';
```

either before or after the definition of `$pdflatex` in `.latexmkrc` does not do anything. Is such thing possible?

NB: in case it matters, my version of `latexmk` (as reported by `-v`) is 4.41

Comment: The latexmk author is on the site, so he'll probably give his take on this at some point. Sounds odd that the lualatex line should not work, but I cannot test until tomorrow. Exactly which OS are you using?

Comment: @daleif I'm using Linux (Debian testing). In case it matters, `perl -v` reports 5.24.1 +60 Debian patches

Comment: If you look in the code there is no `$lualatex`, the `-lualatex` option actually mess with `$pdflatex` (I looked in the latest version on CTAN). You probably need to send a feature request to the author. I agree there ought to be a `$lualatex` variable to play with.

Comment: You're right. I was mislead by your answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305565/27573) mentioning `$lualatex` in the configuration file. That said, I'd be comfortable with `@extra_pdflatex_options` if I can get some assurance that its name and behavior is somewhat stable.

Comment: I'll edit that. I hardly never use xelatex or lualatex

Comment: The situation will change in the next release of `latexmk`.  There'll be `$lualatex` that will do what you want.  (There'll also be a similar `$xelatex` variable.)

Comment: @JohnCollins I am using TeXstudio, so I edited `latexmk` command to be `latexmk -quiet -bibtex -pvc -pdf -lualatex="-synctex=1" %.tex`, but I got an error regarding `synctex`. Could you tell me how it is properly done?

Answer (score 3):

With `latexmk` version 4.61, you can run

```
latexmk -showextraoptions
```

to get a list of options that may be given to `latexmk` and passed through to `(pdf)latex`.  Amongst these options you can find `synctex`, so

```
latexmk -lualatex -synctex=1
```

in one off situations.  In a `latexmkrc` file the section of the man page on advanced configurations shows that one can use `set_tex-commands` for setting options to *all* versions of latex.  So one can write

```
set_tex_cmds( '-synctex=1 %O %S' );
```

and `latexmk -lualatex` will run `lualatex` with `synctex`.

Comment: I had to put a `&` in front of the `set_tex_cmds` to make it work

Comment: It works fine for me without `&` and the above form is given in the documentation of latexmk.  The perl documentation says that `&` is optional when the name is unambiguous, so adding it should do no harm.

Comment: ahh I had forgotten a semicolon on the line before, that was the problem. now it also works w/o `&`

Answer (score 2):

Would creating a latexmkrc file containing `$pdflatex='lualatex -synctex=1 %O %B';`in the same directory as your source file not do the job?

Comment: Yes, but it means that I'd have to remember to copy it in each directory where I need to use `lualatex`, and since it won't be very often, I'll of course forget to do it. Granted, this is a minor annoyance, but I'd prefer a non-local-directory solution.

Answer (score 2):

After exploring `/usr/bin/latexmk`, I've come up with the following `.latexmkrc` which seems to do the trick:

```
push @extra_pdflatex_options, '-synctex=1' ;
$pdf_mode=1;
$pdf_previewer="start okular %O %S";
```

i.e., instead of directly redefining `$pdflatex`, I just add an extra option to be passed to it, and let `latexmk` decide which command it should launch. The only thing that worries me is that as far as I can see `extra_pdflatex_options` is not documented on `latexmk`'s man page, so that I'm unsure about the robustness of this solution against `latexmk` evolution.

Comment: This isn't documented in the latest version, either. But especially with xelatex, this seems to be the safest way to ensure `-synctex=1` and `-c-style-error`, as it uses `-no-pdf` as yet another default switch. The manpage and the official website doesn't mention those arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend just creating a `.latexmkrc` file in your home directory:
Put these two commands or at least the pdflualatex command.

```
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %O %S;';
$pdflualatex = 'lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %O %S;';
```

Then just call latexmk with: `latexmk -lualatex` in any directory and it will use the settings from the home directory.

To override that just put a new latexmkrc file in the compile directory or use the `-r` command of latexmk to pass in a latexmkrc file. I don't put a default latexmkrc but I have an alias in my bash to run the command with `-r` pointing to a default one so this is an option too.