# Make latexmk 4.54c use synctex with xelatex

Tags: xetex, latexmk, forward-inverse-search

I usually want latexmk to use pdflatex and synctex by default, so I have the following in my RC file and everything works hunky-dory:

```
$pdf_mode = 1;
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %O %S';
```

However, some documents I want to compile into PDFs using xelatex and synctex.  How can I change my RC file so that latexmk still uses pdflatex and synctex by default, but if I pass a single command-line option, it will instead use xelatex and synctex?

I tried (among many other things) the following RC file:

```
$pdf_mode = 1;
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %O %S';
$xelatex = 'xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %O %S';
```

With this file, invoking `latexmk` without arguments still works as expected, but running `latexmk -xelatex` or `latexmk -pdfxe` throws an error message:

```
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'foo.pdf'
Latexmk: ===For rule 'xelatex', actual output 'foo.pdf'
       ======appears not to match expected output 'foo.xdv'
Failure to make 'foo.xdv'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  xelatex: failed to create output file
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
```

There is [a previous similar thread on this subject](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/340276/22603) but [the solution given there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340296/22603) works only for older versions of latexmk.  According to [a comment by the author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340276/making-latexmk-use-synctex-1-by-default-with-lualatex#comment841373_340276), the behaviour of the program has since changed, and latexmk should now "do what you want", though I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Try `xelatex -no-pdf -synctex=1  %O %S`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: That works, thanks! If you want to post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: There is nothing to stop you from defining `$pdflatex` from using `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`.

Comment: @HerbSchulz: There is if I don't want xelatex to be the default.

Comment: Related question (answering the question in the title): [luatex - making latexmk use -synctex=1 by default with lualatex - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340276/making-latexmk-use-synctex-1-by-default-with-lualatex) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

latexmk splits the xelatex compilation. From the documentation

> Latexmk first uses xelatex to make an xdv file, and
>   does all the extra runs needed (including those of bibtex, etc). Only after that does it make the pdf
>   file from the xdv file, using xdvipdfmx.

To get this behaviour the original definition for the variable `$xelatex` contains the `-no-pdf` switch:

```
# xelatex is used to give xdv file, not pdf file
$xelatex = 'xelatex -no-pdf %O %S';
```

If you want to change the variable you should use the switch too.

Answer (score 3):

In v4.54c, in addition to adding an `$xelatex` variable, the process was change to run `xelatex` with the `-no-pdf` flag and only run `xdvipdfmx` once at the end of the job, which apparently speeds up compile time. Hence, when running with the `-xelatex` flag, `latexmk` expects an `xdv` output.

There are a couple of options here:

1. Change your `$xelatex` to `$xelatex = -no-pdf -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %O %S`
2. Not dissimilar to the answer in the question you linked, don't overwrite the `$xelatex` variable but instead add `push @extra_xelatex_options, '-synctex=1' ;`.