# Latexmk fails on Windows when output directory is specified

Tags: xetex, miktex, biber, windows, latexmk

Latexmk does not generate the output PDF with XeLaTeX and biber *when an output directory is specified*.

I am using an output directory specified by `-outdir` called `build` to keep my root directory tidy.

I am running MikTeX on Windows 7 x64. Latexmk is version 4.54c.

Here is an MWE.

`test.tex` contains the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{publications.bib}
\begin{document}
\fullcite{InterestingArticle}
\end{document}
```

`publications.bib` contains the following:

```
@article{InterestingArticle,
  author    = {Andrew Bate},
  title     = {Interesting Article Title},
  journal   = {Interesting Journal},
  volume    = {999},
  year      = {1984}
}
```

When I run `latexmk -xelatex -silent -outdir=build` I get the following output, but no PDF in the `build` directory:

```
Use of uninitialized value $separator in regexp compilation at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl line 8553.
Use of uninitialized value $separator in regexp compilation at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl line 8554.
Use of uninitialized value $search_path_separator in concatenation (.) or string at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl line 1882.
Use of uninitialized value $search_path_separator in concatenation (.) or string at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl line 2173.
Use of uninitialized value $print_cmd in string at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl line 2713.
Latexmk: Run number 1 of rule 'xelatex'
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit)
entering extended mode
Latexmk: fls file doesn't appear to have been made
Latexmk: Non-existent bbl file 'build/test.bbl'
 No file test.bbl.
Latexmk: ===For rule 'xelatex', actual output 'I:/bug-report/build/test.xdv'
       ======appears not to match expected output 'build/test.xdv'
Latexmk: Summary of warnings:
  Latex failed to resolve 1 citation(s)
Latexmk: Run number 1 of rule 'biber build/test'
Latexmk: Run number 2 of rule 'xelatex'
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit)
entering extended mode
Latexmk: fls file doesn't appear to have been made
Latexmk: ===For rule 'xelatex', actual output 'I:/bug-report/build/test.xdv'
       ======appears not to match expected output 'build/test.xdv'
Latexmk: Run number 1 of rule 'bibtex I:/bug-report/build/test'
For rule 'bibtex I:/bug-report/build/test', running '&run_bibtex(  )' ...
Latexmk: Directory in file name 'I:/bug-report/build/test.aux' for bibtex
   but it is not the output directory 'build'
I found no \citation commands---while reading file I:/bug-report/build/test.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file I:/bug-report/build/test.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file I:/bug-report/build/test.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  bibtex I:/bug-report/build/test: Bibtex errors: See file 'I:/bug-report/build/test.blg'
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
```

Removing the `-silent` flag makes no difference (but obviously the output is longer).

If the `-outdir` flag is removed, then the PDF is generated correctly (but I would like to use an output directory).

The above example works correctly running on Linux (Ubuntu 17.10) with TeX Live and with latexmk version 4.54c (the same version of latexmk I used on Windows). On Linux, it works both with and without `-outdir` specified.

I am not using a `.latexmkrc` file.

Note the 'Use of uninitialized value' warnings. These don't appear on Linux, but I do not know if this is related.

Any help to get this working is greatly appreciated.

**Update 2018-01-14:** The issue only occurs when the source files are located in a directory on another computer on the network (e.g., a Windows mapped network drive).

The PDF is successfully generated when the source files are in a directory on the local filesystem.

Upgrading from version 4.54c to 4.54d (released 10 January 2018) removes some of the 'Use of uninitialized value' warnings, but the PDF file is still not generated when the source files are located in a network directory. I have filed a bug with John Collins, the author of latexmk.

Comment: `$search_path_separator` seems to be the path separator (`;` under Windows and `:` on Unix-like systems). As far as I can tell, it's initialised in the operating system checks except in the `elsif ( $^O eq "msys" )` block. My guess is that perhaps you're running `latexmk` using MSYS, and the separator variable isn't being set, which is breaking the path search.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I just tested it again, and I'm getting the same output from both Windows Command Prompt and PowerShell. I also tried on a fresh install of Windows 10, and I get the same again.

Comment: At least part of this is covered here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408783/56716

Comment: It might help if you can post your `.latexmkrc` file (if any)

Comment: @ig0774 I am not using a `.latexmkrc` file.

Comment: I'm pretty sure from the warning messages that the problem stems from an uninitialised variable, but it's a good idea to rule out other possibilities. Does it also fail with PDFLaTeX? From the Windows command prompt, what happens if you do `perl -e 'print "$^O\n"'` (it should print the operating system name)?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot To answer your questions: When I run `latexmk -pdf -outdir=build` the PDF is generated correctly, but I still have the 5 'Use of uninitialized value' warnings at the beginning of the output. Also, `perl -e 'print "$^O\n"'` prints `msys` when run from Windows command prompt on both Windows 7 and 10 (I don't know why).

Comment: @AndrewBate I recommend you report it to `latexmk`'s maintainer. The `$search_path_separator` variable isn't being set in the `elsif ( $^O eq "msys" )` block which is the cause of the `Use of uninitialized value` warnings. Since this variable is related to the search path I'm guessing that may be the cause of the failure to find the files, but it's possible there may be something else as well. (Presumably you have an MSYS version of Perl, but I don't know enough about Windows to give further details.)

Comment: Latexmk maintainer here. This is an actual bug in latexmk.  I've uploaded a corrected version to http://personal.psu.edu/jcc8//latexmk/versions.html as v. 4.54d. Could you test it?  I don't have access to a system with MSys, so I can't test it myself.  (You'll need to unpack the distribution's zip file and put latexmk.pl where you can run it.) Contact me at my e-mail in the documentation if you need help.

Comment: Here's a fix you apply without an updated latexmk.  Make yourself a .latexmkrc file, and put the following line in it: `$search_path_separator = ';'; `.

Comment: @JohnCollins Still no PDF is generated (but some of the 'Use of uninitialized value' warnings have gone away). I will email you a bug report with the new output.

Comment: I should have a full fix released soon.  Even after the bug of undefined variables was solved, another annoying problem was found. It was caused by system times not being synchronized between the computer running latexmk and the computer hosting the file system for the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is corrected in `latexmk` v. 4.55.  So just upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: Weirdly, the problem continues to exist in GNU Linux even with v4.55d. If an output directory ,eg 'build/' is specified, it fails to find the bbl file, reports an error and compilation halts. This problem is resolved when trying to build in the root directory,