# How to enable shell escape when building with latexmk and xelatex

Tags: xetex, latexmk, shell-escape

The title already says the question.

I want to clarify that this is not a duplicate, because existing answers are all for plain `latex` or `pdflatex`. Building with `latexmk` and `pdflatex` with shell escape can be done with `latexmk -latex="latex -shell-escape` and `latexmk -pdflatex="pdflatex -shell-escape`, but we cannot change the full command arguments used for `xelatex` when invoking `latexmk -xelatex`.

Comment: Probably related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408783/make-latexmk-4-54c-use-synctex-with-xelatex

Comment: try `latexmk -xelatex -latexoption="-shel-escape" document`

Comment: Or very dirty hack: `latexmk -pdflatex="xelatex -shell-escape"  document`

Comment: @samcarter: The `latexoption` works perfectly, even though it is mentioned nowhere in the manpage. I will accept it if it turns into an answer.

Comment: @SiyuanRen done :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are multiple options:

- `latexmk -xelatex -latexoption="-shell-escape" document`
- `latexmk -xelatex -shell-escape document` (this option is not listed in the normal `latexmk -help` menu, but you have to run `latexmk -showextraoptions` to see it)

Comment: Actually, when I run `latexmk -showextraoptions`, I find out that I can pass `-shell-escape` directly to `latexmk`.

Comment: @SiyuanRen Sure, this is the second option I described.